# Ladda on submit button

Tags: jquery, ladda

I am having troubles with Ladda button that is inside the form and doing the submit. I have tried a lot of things, when I pull button outside the form it's working. I binded ladda like this

```
$('.ladda-button').ladda('bind');
```

Comment: Can you show us a minimal, concrete, verifiable example?

Comment: tried a lot of things, => Please show us whatever you have tried.

Comment: ```<button type="submit" class="ladda-button btn btn-default" data-style="zoom-in">
                <span class="ladda-label">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> {{ 'btn.save'|trans }}
                </span>
            <span class="ladda-spinner"></span>
        </button>
```
is the button, there is not much to try with ladda binding, except selector. When it's outside of form it works, when it's inside - it doesn't.

Comment: And `jQuery` code is inside `$(function () {});` block in script.

Comment: Also button html is in `twig` child template, parent template have the script.